# Coroutine that waits for input with timeout

Tags: kotlin, jvm, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to coroutines, and I'm trying to understand if/how I can leverage them to do something like the following:

1. start listening for events (for example, keyboard input)
2. if an event arrives, react to it (do something)
3. if no event arrives within n seconds, do something else

I was thinking that I might need to make the timeout an event itself.  But I have a hard time wrapping my head around this stuff.  A simple example that performs the above would be very enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Kotlin' own timeout functionality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#timeout).

```
val result = withTimeoutOrNull(timeoutInMillis) {
    var event = getKeybouardEvent()
    while(event == null) {
        event = getKeybouardEvent()
     }
    return event
}
if(result == null) doThis() else doThat()
```

Comment: Accepted because it answers the basic question.  Now, I imagined to keep processing events instead of just once.  I could put this in a `do { ...} while (result != null)` loop, but is that the way to go?  It launches a new coroutine after each event is processed, so not sure if there's no unnecessary overhead there.

Comment: Also, `getKeyboardEvent` would be a suspending function in this case, right?

Comment: Actually, if that would be the case, the inner `while` loop wouldn't be necessary.  Did you have busy polling in mind when you gave that example?

Comment: To answer my first comment above myself: it seems coroutines are lightweight enough to launch a lot, accoring to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutines-are-light-weight

Comment: @herman 1) Launching coroutines is free lunch, as you found out yourself. 2) You have several possibilities to restart this timer, like: do/while, another coroutine which sends events into a channel: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html

Comment: I would definitely recommend against busy-spinning like this. There's surely a way to get a keyboard event that uses callbacks and doesn't have to poll.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik indeed, I'll probably send events into the coroutine through a channel.